# Strange behaiver of localStorage with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, local-storage, puppeteer

Im trying to save the localStorage to a variable outside of the page.evaluate(). But it seems that i cant do it. Below is the code im trying to use and outputs of consloe.log()'s , how i can make it to work and save the localStorage to a variable ? Inside the callback i can see the localStorage, but it dont act regular as getItem isnt working.

I'm trying several ways to get the data but none seems to work... any idea why?

```
await page.click("[id=Login-button]");

let savedLocalStorage = "";

const result = await page.evaluate(savedLocalStorage => {
console.log(localStorage); //output: {AUTH: 12345}

console.log(localStorage.key(0)); //output: null

console.log(localStorage.getItem("AUTH")); //output: null

localStorage.setItem("Test", "1234"); //working

console.log(localStorage); //output: {AUTH: 12345, Test: 1234}

savedLocalStorage = localStorage;

//savedLocalStorage = localStorage.AUTH; - same result as savedLocalStorage = localStorage;

return localStorage;
}, savedLocalStorage);

console.log(savedLocalStorage); //output: ""

console.log(result); //output: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try serializing the data,:

```
    async function saveLocalStorage(page, filePath) {
      const json = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const json = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
          const key = localStorage.key(i);
          json[key] = localStorage.getItem(key);
        }
        return json;
      });
      fs.writeFileSync(filePath, 'utf8', JSON.stringify(json));
    }

    async function restoreLocalStorage(page, filePath) {
      const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'));
      await page.evaluate(json => {
        localStorage.clear();
        for (let key in json)
          localStorage.setItem(key, json[key]);
      }, json);
    }
```

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/727

Comment: Thanks for trying, but still not working, tried also Object.assign({}, localStorage); and not working..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you won't be able to pass `savedLocalStorage` as a reference. The script inside the `evaluate` will get a serialized copy of that variable.

Regarding the `result`. Puppetter won't return a serialized localStorage but a pointer (JSHandle) to the object inside the browser. It's basically a puppeteer object you can pass to another `evaluate` function, in this case "as a reference".

What you could do is serialize the localStorage and then parse it on the other side.

```js
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("Test", "1234"); //working
  return JSON.stringify(localStorage);
});

console.log(JSON.parse(result));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>console.log test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      localStorage.setItem("AUTH", 12345);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, now i can see {Test: 1234} but i cannot see {AUTH: 12345} so its not helping me, i actually interested in the AUTH , do you know why i cant see it?

Comment: Are you sure it's there?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned console.log(localStorage); in the call back prints {AUTH: 12345} in the dev tools of puppeteer window. (headless mode false).

Comment: Do you know who is setting that value and how?

Comment: What do you mean by who? I think the issue that need to be focused (and which will solve this) is why localStorage.getItem() isnt working, while localStorage.set() is working...

Comment: I edited my answer. With an example page. That's working for me. Even returning `localStorage.getItem("AUTH");` I'm saying so, so you can debug and check when that value is being set. The feature is working correctly.